# Retrieving specific chracters based on their Unicode code pont

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a set of 40 characters that have their own code points. For example, `U0678`, `u0679` and so on. How to retrieve words, strings and sub strings that only contain those characters from the text based on their code point, ignoring all other characters? I'm suffering with my old code

```
private string token(string x)
{
    Regex exclude = new Regex(@"\d|\s+|/|-|[A-Za-z]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return string.Join(" ",
      (from s in Regex.Split(x, "([ \\t{}():;.,!ـ؛،؟ \"\n])")
       where !exclude.IsMatch(s)
       select s).ToArray());
}
```

Edited. Assume i have the string "aaa bbb ccc ddd ". Then I would like to retrieve the words aaa and bbb only. then I would like to do something like

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"\u0041|\u0042");
Match match = regEx.Match(mystring);
if(match.Success)
 then do somthing
```

But i have 40 characters.

Comment: Again, the question is unclear. Add examples. And what does 'suffering' mean here?

Comment: @ Henk, it is just like to retrieve all English words from a text based on the characters Unicode code point.

Comment: @Qaesar Perhaps you should provide sample inputs/outputs. Given a sample input `x`, what are the expected string(s) returned?

Comment: Ok, so you have a set of space delimited strings, and a set of 40 characters. You wish to find which of those strings (separated by spaces) are built up of _only_ combinations of those 40 characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ok, so you have a set of space delimited strings, and a set of 40 characters. You wish to find which of those strings (separated by spaces) are built up of only combinations of those 40 characters?
>
> @ Chris, yes, exactly .

```
var charSet = new HashSet<char>("abcde\x015f" + Regex.Unescape("\u0066"));
//or var charSet = new HashSet<char>(new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'ş', 'f'});
//or var charSet = new HashSet<char>(new[] { '\x0061', '\x0062', '\x0063', '\x0064', '\x0065', '\x015F', '\x0066'});
//or var charSet = new HashSet<char>(Regex.Unescape("\u0061\u0062\u0063\u0064\u0065\u015F\u0066"));
//or var charSet = new HashSet<char>("\x0061\x0062\x0063\x0064\x0065\x015F\x0066");

string input = "abc  defş aaa xyz";

var words =  input.Split()
                .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                .Where(s => s.All(c => charSet.Contains(c)))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Can I use the code points instead ofthe char to fill the hash set ??

Comment: @ L.B. The thing is that i have 40 characters. can I put their code points in the hashset instead of the characters themselves ?